# Unable to bootstrap to the node

Tags: chef-infra

I have tried to bootstrap to the IP address given. But it states that:

```
Starting Chef Client, version 11.16.4

Creating a new client identity for chef02 using the validator key.

 ======================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "chef02"
 ======================================================================

Resource Not Found:
 -------------------
The server returned a HTTP 404. This usually indicates that your chef
l is incorrect.

Relevant Config Settings:
 -------------------------
chef_server_url

FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cac
acktrace.out

Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 0.817298561 seconds

ERROR: 404 "Not Found"

FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeErr
un process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you `chef_server_url` value in your knife.rb config is incorrect. First check that basic knife commands such as `knife client list` succeed from your workstation. If that is the case, then try checking if the hostname in your `chef_server_url` resolves differently from the target machine.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For knife client list is not working. Can't I use IP address? Must I have to use hostname?

Comment: The URL just needs to be a valid thing that knife (and Chef in general) can make HTTP requests to. Assuming the IP is reachable from your workstation, `http://1.2.3.4/` should work fine. How did you configure your Chef Server?

Comment: I download the package from  http://downloads.getchef.com/chef-server/ (Chef server version 12) and run the command sudo dpkg -i chef-server-core_12.0.0-rc.4-1_amd64.deb

Comment: You should use the Chef Manage web interface to setup your organization. Download the Starter Kit zip file, in there you will find a working knife.rb config file and the other things you need.

Comment: I trying out using Open Source Chef Server, not using Chef Manage web interface :)

Comment: No, you are using Chef Server 12, not Open Source Chef Server (which is now discontinue in favor of the unified 12 version). Setting up Chef Server 12 without the web interface is currently an advanced operation and not something I recommend to new users.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for clearing my doubts. So only Open Source Chef Server 11 right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. From what you said, you did not install Chef Server 11.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue, i was able to browse the webui but all knife commands failed. there is link in the ui that is availabl