# Not able to execute knife client list

Tags: chef-infra

I did bootstrap the node but it fails, so no point trying to run the command

> knife client list

right?

Comment: This is a broad follow on to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519963/unable-to-bootstrap-to-the-node

Answer (score 1):

If the bootstrapping of a chef node fails so early that the node didn't register itself at the chef server, then it will not be visible from your workstation.

As soon as it used the validation key (if you use that feature) and a it registers itself as a new client (and finally starts the chef run), *then* you should see it as client. E.g. if the cookbook execution exits with a failure, the client is already registered (as it was able to retrieve its run list).